# "My car is occupied" or "My car is engaged"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence, phrase-usage

Suppose your mum has taken your car to buy groceries, and your colleague wants you to pick him up.
How do you tell him without going into the details?

> Sorry, my car is occupied right now.

OR

> Sorry, my car is engaged right now.

I used the first one but it didn't sound right. Is there any other way to say this?
`

Comment: My car is in use right now.

Comment: Thanks. And about the ones I mentioned, is that wrong english?

Comment: We don't use the ones you mentioned.

Comment: They are not grammatically wrong, but we use those words of a room (particularly a bathroom), so they feel rather amusingly inappropriate.

Comment: "My car is engaged right now" means it's in gear.

Comment: @HotLicks -  or it has promised to marry that cute little van it met at the supermarket parking lot. Maybe because it has to?

Comment: @SS, Writing english instead of English will make others think that the writer is less serious, though he may not be so.

Comment: @KateBunting Haha I'll keep that in mind. :D

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you